# initializing a struct array with array inside

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I made a struct with a with an uninitialized array inside but the outer struct is an array that is initialized. I then loop through and print the values but I'm not getting anything. NUM is already defined as 12.

```
#include "header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void make() {

struct suit {
    char *type;
    int people[];
} deck[4] = {"Hunter", NUM,
    "Fighter", NUM,
    "Jumper", NUM,
    "Strider", NUM};





};
//print type and numbers 1-12
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < NUM; i++) {
        printf(deck[i].type);
        printf(deck[i].people[j]);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Have you even read the basics of C? Your `printf`'s are wrong. I don't think your code even compiles successfully.

Comment: Which compiler you are using?

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: I think there are multiple problems in code. In addition to the one indicated in the answer, the printf does not have any format specifier to print integer.

Comment: Your initializer is illegal - the compiler should tell you there is a problem

Comment: No I've gotten error: non-static initialization of a flexible array member. I did try a few things that did make it compile but those weren't outputting anything.

Comment: can you post your complete code with main().

Answer (score -1):

`people` is a flexible array member and Standard C does not allow initialization of flexible array member. Though, GCC allows [static initialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) of flexible array as an extension. So,

```
 struct suit {
    char *type;
    int people[];
 } deck = {"Hunter", NUM};
```

is valid snippet as per GCC, but at the same time GCC doesn't allow nested array initialization when flexible array member is involved and therefore the initializer for `deck[4]` is not valid.

> Of course, this extension only makes sense if the extra data comes at the end of a top-level object, as otherwise we would be overwriting data at subsequent offsets. To avoid undue complication and confusion with initialization of deeply nested arrays, we simply disallow any non-empty initialization except when the structure is the top-level object. For example:
>
> ```
>  struct foo { int x; int y[]; };
>  struct bar { struct foo z; };
>
>  struct foo a = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };        // Valid.
>  struct bar b = { { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } } };    // Invalid.
>  struct bar c = { { 1, { } } };            // Valid.
>  struct foo d[1] = { { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } } };  // Invalid.
> ```

Also note that you should use appropriate format specifiers in `printf` for different data types.

Answer (score -1):

Allocate the memory of `int people[];` array, So, your struct should look like this, since it is an object definition:

```
struct suit {
    char *type;
    int people[10]; //compile time allocation
} deck[4] = {"Hunter", NUM,
    "Fighter", NUM,
    "Jumper", NUM,
    "Strider", NUM};
```

Comment: You've got the right idea that the size of `people` needs to be specified, however you also need to brace the intiializer for each element of `deck`. Otherwise `"Fighter"` is taken as the initializer for `deck[0].people[1]` and so on.